# Proof that $\left<M\right>_{S_n}$ has finite expectation

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, quadratic-variation

Let $M$ be a continuous martingale with $M_0=0$ and $S_n:=\inf \{t:|M_t|>n\}$. Show using Ito's Isometry that $\langle M\rangle_{S_n}$ has finite expectation for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I know that $S_n$ is a stopping time. But abit stuck on how Ito's Isometry can be used to proceed.

In general I think it's quite difficult to gain intuition on this topic so that one could go about approaching the exercises. Can some one give pointers to good notes and textbooks?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:** By definition, $(M_{t \wedge S_n}^2- \langle M \rangle_{t \wedge S_n})_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale and therefore $$\mathbb{E}(\langle M \rangle_{t \wedge S_n}) = \mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge S_n}^2).$$ Since $M$ has continuous sample paths, this implies

$$\mathbb{E}(\langle M \rangle_{t \wedge S_n}) \leq n^2.$$

By monotone convergence,

$$\mathbb{E}(\langle M \rangle_{S_n}) \leq n^2.$$

Comment: i think the isometry part maybe comes in by continuing on the above argument, and realising that by Martingale Representation Theorem we can write $M_{t\land S_n}=c+\int_0^{t\land S_n}H_u dW_u$ so that $M_{t\land S_n}^2=c^2+2c\int_0^{t\land S_n}H_u dW_u+\left(\int_0^{t\land S_n}H_u dW_u\right)^2$. This means that $\mathbb{E}\left[ M_{t\land S_n}^2 \right]=c^2 + \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\int_0^{t\land S_n}H_u dW_u\right)^2 \right]=c^2 + \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^{t\land S_n}H_u^2 dt \right]$, which is finite by construction. Does this make sense?

Comment: @bigfatwhale Yeah, but this is overkill, from my point of view. Actually, the equality $$\mathbb{E}(\langle M \rangle_{t \wedge S_n}) = \mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge S_n}^2)$$ (which I used in my answer) *is* in some sense an Itô isometry. Just write down the equality e.g. for $$M_t = \int_0^t H_u \, dW_u.$$